# best way to call graphql mutations from an Azure Function

Tags: azure, graphql, azure-functions, graphql-js

I want to call a graph ql mutation from azure function in node.js
Do we have any packages for this? Is the curl best way to do this?

Comment: What's the best way to do that in node.js app outside Azure Functions?

Answer (score 1):

You could easily make a POST request against the GraphQL endpoint with the mutation in the body. Alternatively you could look at using the ApolloClient library to give you more GraphQL utilities.

Comment: do we have example implementations for the same?